# Having problems getting Samba4 and Bind9 working together because of apparmor

Tags: server, samba, bind, apparmor

So I've been following the Samba4 HOWTO, which has gone reasonably well. The issue I'm having is I can't get BIND9 to restart when the samba configuration is included in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
include "/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf";
```

But when I try and restart Bind9 with `sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart` I get the error in my logs:

```
Oct 18 20:25:00 xxxx kernel: [  251.397899] type=1400 audit(1350588300.188:16):    
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1807 profile="/usr/sbin/named"    
name="/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf" pid=1810 comm="named" requested_mask="r"
denied_mask="r" fsuid=105 ouid=0
```

I've got the following rules in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` (which I thought were a bit OTT but I've been debugging for hours now)

```
    /var/lib/samba/ rw,
    /var/lib/samba/* rw,
    /var/lib/samba/private/ rw,
    /var/lib/samba/private/* rw,
    /var/lib/samba/private/dns/ rw,
    /var/lib/samba/private/dns/* rw,
```

For completeness, the perms on the offending file are:

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  384 Oct 17 11:39 named.conf
```

I tried putting apparmor into complain mode, disabling the named profile, and bind9 starts perfectly and Samba works. But as soon as I restart the box, it's broke again, and I'd prefer to understand whats going on then taking bits of the servers's security out to make stuff work.

```
    ~ sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/named
    Setting /usr/sbin/named to complain mode.
    ~ sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
    * Stopping domain name service... bind9

    rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
    ...done.
     * Starting domain name service... bind9
       ...done.
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've done (after some trial and error):

```
$ cat /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.named.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
  /var/lib/samba/private/named.conf r,
  /var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab kwr,
  /usr/lib/samba/** m,
  /var/lib/samba/private/dns/** krw,
  /var/tmp/** krw,
  /dev/urandom rw,

$ service apparmor reload

$ service bind9 start
```

It should work fine then.